# Special chacacters in python 3.3

Tags: python, unicode, special-characters, decoder

I'm trying to do a small decoder.
I want to assign the value `'a'` to the special letter `"("`
example: `( = "a"`
and if I input `"("` it prints it to `"a"` like:

If I enter `"(%!)("`:

It prints the equivalent for each character like:

```
LadyBa
```

Hope you understand what I mean!
I know it need unicode or something like that but I'm not very good at python
I'm trying to learn.
Working on windows python 3.3

Comment: Have you looked at python dictionaries at all? They let you map one thing to another thing.

Comment: I dont think that it relates to list.  
I wanna use special charcters as input and as variable

Comment: if `"("` equals `"a"` then why there's only a single `"a"` in `"(%!)("`?

Comment: It was an example don't take the string so literaly.  
I was just trying to explain the idea

Comment: Well, your can try explaining it better...

Comment: @KillerB then explain the idea with correct examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: this is good, thanks to Ashwini Chaudhary

```
>>> d = {'(': 'a'}
>>> "".join(d.get(x,x) for x in 'text with m(ny letters')
'text with many letters'
```

This is a longer solution but does the equivalent:

So you want to translate letters and keep thoos untouched that you do not know?

```
>>> d = {'(': 'a'}
>>> ''.join(map(lambda letter: d.get(letter, letter), 'text with m(ny letters'))
'text with many letters'
```

**Explanation**

---

This

```
d.get(letter, letter)
```

tries to find the letter in d and if not present returns letter (the second letter)

---

```
lambda letter: lalala
```

is the same as

```
def f(letter):
    return lalala
f # return f
```

---

```
map(function, list)
```

does this:

```
[function(element) for element in list]
```

which is a short form of

```
l = []
for element in list:
    l.append(function(element))
l # returns that list
```

---

```
''.join(list)
```

is the same as

```
string = ''
for element in list:
    string += element
string # return string as result
```

Comment: As I am noob on python I understand only the first line.Please try to explain it.

Comment: why lambda? just use: `"".join(d.get(x,x) for x in 'text with m(ny letters')`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `str.translate`:

```
In [7]: trans = str.maketrans("(","a")

In [8]: "(bcd(".translate(trans)
Out[8]: 'abcda'
```

> S.translate(table [,deletechars]) -> string
>
> Return a copy of the string S, where all characters occurring in the
>   optional argument deletechars are removed, and the remaining
>   characters have been mapped through the given translation table, which
>   must be a string of length 256 or None. If the table argument is None,
>   no translation is applied and the operation simply removes the
>   characters in deletechars.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    trans = string.maketrans()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans' 
I get this error

Comment: @KillerB fixed, this one works in py3.x.

Comment: can this be used to assign more values in a row, like  
tra = str.maketrans("(","a","&","b" and continue)

Comment: can this be used to assign more values in a row, like tra = str.maketrans("(","a","&","b" and continue)